# Check property type at runtime and give the same type to Generic lambda expression parameter T

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, lambda

I have some code snippet given as below:

Want to resolve this conditation by checking the type at runtime.

```
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("propertyName");

var expression = new Object(); // this give me error after expression runs!

    // Want to resolve this conditation by checking the type at runtime.
    if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
               // Want to pass the generic type parameter which has a same type created at runtime by identifying the property type.
                expression = BuildExpression<T, DateTime>(data, group.Member);
            }

private Func<T, V> BuildExpression<T, V>(IEnumerable<T> items, string propertyName)
    {
      Type type = typeof(T);
      PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
      Type PropertyType = pi.DeclaringType;
      var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), propertyName);
      var cast = Expression.TypeAs(parameter, pi.DeclaringType);
      var getterBody = Expression.Property(cast, pi);
      var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, V>>(getterBody, parameter);
      return exp.Compile();
    }
```

**Problem:**
I have to write condition on type  I have to check the type of property by reflection and then have to build the expression.

**What I want:**
I want to check the runtime time the Type of property and want to build runtime Generic parameter of that type which is same as a property type.

Basically I want to remove the `If` condition *on type checking* and What I want is, the code should `automatically detect the property type` and pass the same type in `Generic parameter argument`, so that I don't have to check with all the types with `If` condition. Like for `string, decimal, double etc..`

Could you please do let me know that resolution as I want to check the `property` type at runtime and want to create `Generic parameter type` with the *same type as property has*.

Comment: well, what is your `BuildExpression` method? and could it take a `Type` parameter rather than a `T` generic?

Comment: Marc, It's taking generic parameter type. I have added the same method within the question.

Comment: and what is the type of your `expression` local variable?

Comment: That's I am wondering because I am not sure about how would I initialize my local variable because it will be different for different type checking at runtime.. I have posted the code above on my opinion where it should be like it. BUT not sure how to deal with this type of condition... I have initialize with "var expression = new Object();", BUT it gives me error after expression runs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a method that returns `Func<T,V>` (for object `T` and member-type `V`) is problematic, because you can't really do anything useful with that at runtime. You can't assign it to a typed delegate without knowing the `T` and `V` at compile time, and using `DynamicInvoke` is not a great idea. Frankly, you would be better building a `Func<object,object>`, and just dealing with `object` at runtime. Reflection and generics do not mix well.

```
private static Func<object, object> BuildExpression(
    Type type, string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var body = Expression.TypeAs(Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.TypeAs(
        parameter, type), propertyName), typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(body, parameter).Compile();
}
```

However, at that point you could, IMO, just switch to a library like [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember), and use name-based access:

```
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type);
var obj = ...
var propVal = accessor[obj, propertyName];
```

Comment: Marc, Thanks for the info. After using your method, I am getting LamdaExpression for <Object, Object>. That's fine. Lets assume that, I want to build with 'integer' type lamda expression out of this. How would I convert the result from your method to 'Integer' expression ??

Comment: @nunu having it as an "integer expression" causes huge problems, since you can't have a variable that is "an integer expression or a string expression or a datetime expression or ..." - you *can*, however, have "an object expression". What exactly do you want to do? how would you see yourself using it if it was an integer expression?

Comment: what I want to do here is, Whatever result (Func<object,object>) I am getting from your method 'BuildExpression<object, object>, I want to use that result Func<object,objcet> in 'GroupBy' extension method of IEnumerable.  E.g. var expResult = BuildExpression(typeof(T), "City"); var gropupedResult = myList.GroupBy(expResult);  How would I achieve this?

Comment: @nunu I wouldn't to start with; I might, however, write a custom `GroupBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, string memberName)`, basically borrowing the code from this custom `OrderBy` answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505